# What is the equivalent command of "express-generator --view=pug my_app" for "express-generator-typescript"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, pug, express-generator

In JavaScript version of NodeJS there is a command as `express-generator --view=pug my_app`, but what about `express-generator-typescript`?

Does `--view=pug` also works with TypeScript version of NodeJS or we should use another option? Or maybe it uses `Pug` by default?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I'm the creator of express-generator-typescript. There's no template engine options for this library. Because so many people are using SPAs these days I didn't think there was any point. You're free to create a pull request if you'd like though.